# java htmlunit failing to load Javascript

Tags: java, htmlunit

What is causing this error, and how do I fix it?

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Error message

> May 25, 2013 10:34:12 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:13 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
>   SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.] sourceName=[http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js] line=[2] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:15 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:16 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
>   WARNING: CSS error: 'cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=1748204ca390' [1:3230] Error in style rule. (Invalid token "!". Was expecting one of: , , , "inherit", , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , "}", ";", "/", "-".)
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:16 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
>   WARNING: CSS warning: 'cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=1748204ca390' [1:3230] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:16 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
>   WARNING: CSS error: 'cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=1748204ca390' [1:6341] Error in style rule. (Invalid token "!". Was expecting one of: , , , "inherit", , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , "}", ";", "/", "-".)
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:16 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
>   WARNING: CSS warning: 'cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=1748204ca390' [1:6341] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:16 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
>   WARNING: CSS error: 'cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=1748204ca390' [1:14777] Error in style rule. (Invalid token "!". Was expecting one of: , , , "inherit", , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , "}", ";", "/", "-".)
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:16 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
>   WARNING: CSS warning: 'cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=1748204ca390' [1:14777] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:17 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
>   WARNING: CSS error: 'cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=1748204ca390' [1:31657] Error in style rule. (Invalid token "!". Was expecting one of: , , , "inherit", , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , "}", ";", "/", "-".)
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:17 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
>   WARNING: CSS warning: 'cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=1748204ca390' [1:31657] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:17 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
>   WARNING: CSS error: 'cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=1748204ca390' [1:73253] Error in style rule. (Invalid token ":". Was expecting one of: , , , "inherit", , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , "}", ";", "/", "-".)
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:17 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
>   WARNING: CSS warning: 'cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=1748204ca390' [1:73253] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:17 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
>   WARNING: CSS error: 'cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=1748204ca390' [1:112886] Error in expression. (Invalid token "#ffffff". Was expecting one of: , , , , , , , "-", "=", ")".)
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:17 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
>   WARNING: CSS error: 'cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=1748204ca390' [1:112928] Error in style rule. (Invalid token "background". Was expecting one of: , "}", ";".)
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:17 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler warning
>   WARNING: CSS warning: 'cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=1748204ca390' [1:112928] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:19 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.ActiveXObject jsConstructor
>   WARNING: Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.7'.
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:19 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
>   SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.7'.] sourceName=[http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js] line=[25] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:19 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.ActiveXObject jsConstructor
>   WARNING: Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.6'.
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:19 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
>   SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.6'.] sourceName=[http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js] line=[25] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:19 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.ActiveXObject jsConstructor
>   WARNING: Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash'.
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:19 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
>   SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[Automation server can't create object for 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash'.] sourceName=[http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js] line=[25] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:20 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:21 AM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
>   WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: azk-views=; Max-Age=31536000000; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 25 May 2014 17:34:42 GMT". Invalid max-age attribute: 31536000000
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:21 AM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
>   WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: azk-events=; Max-Age=2592000000; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 24 Jun 2013 17:34:42 GMT". Invalid max-age attribute: 2592000000
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:21 AM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
>   WARNING: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: azk-voting=; Max-Age=2592000000; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 24 Jun 2013 17:34:42 GMT". Invalid max-age attribute: 2592000000
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:21 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
>   WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
>   May 25, 2013 10:34:23 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptJobManagerImpl runSingleJob
>   SEVERE: Job run failed with unexpected RuntimeException: Exception invoking setInnerHTML

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Those are not errors, they are **warnings**.

They are caused by HtmlUnit's JavaScript engine [Mozilla’s Rhino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29) being unable to properly interpret some JavaScript code. (It is not as "good" as some other popular JS Engines.)

You can turn those warnings off, here's how:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // turn off htmlunit warnings
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://stackoverflow.com");
    System.out.println(page.getTitleText());
}
```

Output:

```
Stack Overflow
```

Answer (score 1):

Set enable Javascript and CSS in the `webClient` browser as:

```
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
```

You can <kbd>ON</kbd> / <kbd>OFF</kbd> by passint true or false parameters.